# Variable variables concept confusion

Tags: php

Hey guys am a newbie in PHP. I have seen some code like:

```
<?php
class foo {
    var $bar = 'I am bar.';
    var $arr = array('I am A.', 'I am B.', 'I am C.');
    var $r = 'some';
}

$foo = new foo();
$arr = 'arr';
echo $foo->$arr[1];
?>
```

It returns `some`. Why it is returning `some`. `echo $foo->$arr[1]` means it should output `I am B`. But instead it outputs `some`; why?

Comment: I do not know why anyone downvoted this, +1 upvoting.

Answer (score 5):

When you access a property of a class, you don't use `$` before the property.  If you do, it will evaluate that portion first, to figure out what property to access.

```
echo $foo->$arr[1];
```

`$arr` is 'arr', so when you access it as an array, it will grab the letter at whatever index you specify.

`$arr[1]` is `"r"`;

`$foo->r` = 'some';

If you access the object property without the `$`:

```
echo $foo->arr[1];
```

it will output I am B.

As a side note, if you DO want to use variable-variables, and it's an array, you should really use parenthesis.

```
$foo->$arr[1];
```

is ambiguous as to whether you mean

```
($foo->$arr)[1];
```

or

```
$foo->($arr[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
   <?php
       class foo {
         public $bar = 'I am bar.';
         public $arr = array('I am A.', 'I am B.', 'I am C.');
         public $r = 'some';
       }

       $foo = new foo();
       echo $foo->arr[1];
   ?>
```

To access object variable have to use $foo->var_name;